# Solving linear system of equations by block

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, computational-mathematics

I want to solve the following large system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
 \left[\begin{array}{cc} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c} x_{1} \\ x_{2} \end{array} \right]= \left[\begin{array}{c} b_{1} \\ b_{2} \end{array} \right] . 
\end{align}

Do people ever solve this system by iterating equations $ A_{11}x_{1} = b_{1} - A_{12} x_{2} $ and $ A_{22}x_{2} = b_{2} - A_{21} x_{1} $? It seems like this could be efficient, since we can calculate the LU decomposition of $ A_{11} $ and $ A_{22} $ faster than we can calculate the LU decomposition of $ \left[\begin{array}{cc} A_{11} & A_{12} \\ A_{21} & A_{22} \end{array}\right] $.

Comment: I don't get why this makes computing the LU decomposition faster?

Comment: The difficulty of the LU decomposition grows cubicly with the size of the matrix. So calculating the LU decomposition of $ A_{11} $ should only take 1/8th as long as calculating the LU decomposition of the full matrix $ A $.

Comment: Look up block versions of Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel methods